# operating 2 camera for motion detection in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, parallel-processing

I am using two camera for motion detection. THese cameras are facing against each other.  i wrote matlab code for single camera and it is working. Now i need to add one more camera. I did so, but the processing speed is so slow many moving object goes undetected. I am looking at block processing and parallel computing tools in matlab but have not figured out how to do it. Also, can GUI be used in image processing for parallel computation. If so how? Your help is appreciated!
Thank You.

Comment: When you mean two cameras are you talking about actual video cameras or some other mathematical process. I have not used MatLab in a long while.

Comment: Maybe you need to consider shifting to C++/OpenCV for faster processing...